# Exporting numerical value as barcode in JSPDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, barcode, jspdf, html-to-pdf

I have the following code:

```
var doc = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
var specialElementHandlers = {
  '#bypassme': function(element, renderer) {
    return true;
  }
};

doc.fromHTML(
  $('#generalDiv').html(), 10, 10,
  {
    'width': 250,'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
  }
);

doc.output('dataurl');
}
```

and My html is this one

```
<div id="generalDiv"> 
123456
</div>
```

Do you know if there is a method in jspdf plugin to render the nmbers as a barcode?
Or do you know another way to do it?

Comment: "Render as a barcode" is a completely different application separate from jsPDF. There's not a reason why it should be a plugin or included in any way..try looking in relevant places

Comment: So I need to generate an image first and then add it to the jspdf? or with CSS and then renther the html ? what do you advice?

Comment: Indeed render the barcode as an image, (native with jsPDF) and add it to the pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it, the answer was to use `jquery-barcode` to generate the barcode, then use the `html2canvas.js` to convert the container div with the bar code to a canvas, and then convert it to an image  and export it as PDF.

```
 html2canvas($("#testcase"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {

            var imgData = canvas.toDataURL(
                'image/png');              
            var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
            doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0);
            doc.save('REQUEST.pdf');
        }
    });
```

Comment: this idea is working for me but i have one problem.since i have converted it to canvas first ,then pdf..resulted pdf is not clear...for that case what should i do?

Comment: define clear, you can search for different combinations of parameters for the function: jsPDF('p', 'mm');

Comment: which combinations of parameters should i give to get a clear pdf.i get a pdf but with barcode but barcodes are not clear

Comment: Try changing parameters in barcode constructor, here there are  some options: http://barcode-coder.com/en/barcode-jquery-plugin-201.html

And to the jspdf constructor this are the parameters :

jsPDF(orientation, unit, format);